# Cant get the Search method to actually look for the desired String and count occurences in an ArrayList of objects, java

Tags: java

This is what i have done so far, it just counts whatever the ArrayList has as having the searched word. Giving me the count of original array but not printing any matching results.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        animalList.add(new Dog("Dog", 43.3, "Husky", 1));
        animalList.add(new Dog("Dog", 80.5, "Labrador", 2));
        animalList.add(new Dog("Dog", 33.1, "Shiba Inu", 1));
        animalList.add(new Dog("Dog", 120.8, "Malamute", 2));
        animalList.add(new Dog("Dog", 43.3, "Chiwawa", 0));
        animalList.add(new Cat("Cat", 14.3, "Short Hair"));
        animalList.add(new Cat("Cat", 11.2, "Siamese"));
        animalList.add(new Cat("Cat", 15.1, "Bengal"));
        animalList.add(new Cat("Cat", 9.6, "Persian"));
        animalList.add(new Bird("Bird", 2.5, "White Plumage", false));
        animalList.add(new Bird("Bird", 1.2, "Long Beak", true));
        animalList.add(new Bird("Bird", 0.3, "Colorful", true));
        animalList.add(new Bird("Bird", 3.6, "Swims", true));

        searchForAnimalClass(animalList, "Bird");
        

    }

    private static ArrayList<Animal> searchForAnimalClass(ArrayList<Animal> list, String animalClass){
        ArrayList<Animal> result= new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        for(Animal x:list) {
            if(x.getAnimalClass().contains(animalClass));
            count++;
            if(x instanceof Animal)
            result.add(x);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of animals with Animal Class of '" + animalClass + "', is equal to = " + count);
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Put a print at searchForAnimalClass(animalList, "Bird"); to print the returned value

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of why you should avoid using `if` without "{ }". Your first `if` condition is basically doing nothing because of bad indentation. Try the following:

```java
private static ArrayList<Animal> searchForAnimalClass(ArrayList<Animal> list, String animalClass){
    ArrayList<Animal> result= new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    for(Animal x:list) {
        if(x.getAnimalClass().contains(animalClass)) {
            count++;
        }
        if(x instanceof Animal) {
            result.add(x);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of animals with Animal Class of '" + animalClass + "', is equal to = " + count);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: More like he actually put a semicolon at the end of the condition but I agree that using the curly braces for if statements is the better option

Comment: Thank you, that worked

Comment: In that case, consider accepting the answer as correct (and if you feel like it also upvote it) so that others can benefit from it and the question can be "closed". Thanks ;)